# I am using UDP Socket programming in java and need to send data over a noisy bridge

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

I am using UDP Socket programming in java and need to send data over a noisy bridge.What i have done till now is the client is sending the message to servery but as i told the bridge contains some noisy so what should i do to send successfully message. I am giving code of Bridge. Can anybody help.Thanks in advance

Comment: With UDP you need to detect when a packet failed to be received and send it again. This is the sort of thing TCP does for you.

Comment: But sir i need to used UDP only. What i am doing is setting a timer for 5sec. and waiting for message is received and resending it. But the bridge is noisy provided by them what should i do??? Help

Comment: What i want is to send the message correctly at once without changing the bridge code provided by them. I am sending data with checksum and at receiver side  i am comparing both checksums if it is equal i am resending the acknowledgement.

Comment: What do you mean by noisy? Do you mean you have a high packet loss?  You probably don't need to wait 5 seconds as this is much longer than the time it takes a packet to go to the moon and back. I would look at how often it typically takes now e.g. 100 ms and double it and resend after 200 ms.  This will allow you to retry earlier, possibly multiple times.

Comment: Do you send a negative acknowledgement when you detect a packet was missing? i.e. you ahve a sequence number in the packet and if this jumps, you ask to have those packets resent immediately.

Comment: Noisy means that they are using two case random no is generated either the message is lost not send to server or changes are made to bytes of message.

Comment: no actually i am just sending an checksum,data and sequence no. and on serverside i tries to check the checksum of both if they are equal acknowledgement is sent.

Comment: Can you please help?

Comment: Creating reliable protocol by using UDP is not trivial task. There are lot of unexpected pitfalls. Don't reinvent TCP or SCTP again. UDP is good, when data lost can be accepted for achieve something (for example better lag).

Comment: So what should i do to recover my data

Answer (score 0):

In short, I would

- Send a negative acknowledgement when a gap in the sequence numbers is sent.
- I would resend much more often, up to the point that the line saturates. Possibly resend after 100 ms or less.
- If the data is short, I send two pieces of data in a packet to increase the chances of it getting through.
- I would send an acknowledgement which implies that a range of values are acknowledged e.g. everything up to that point, for cases where the acknowledgement is corrupted.

Comment: How can i do all these in java?

Comment: I am sending the whole message at once.

Comment: @VishalSharma what have you tried and what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Can i get you mail?
I have setup a simple clienmt server using the bridge provided by them, the client sends the message that consists of checksum datalength and sequence no. At server side first the checksum are compared if it returns true a datagram again send back the received message. What i want is if there is wrong message received what should i do to make it correctly send to server

Comment: This is an assignment they say find right recovery method for loss and error."Using only a checksum and a binary sequence number byte you must implement a strategy to make all packets from server to client received fully without error."

Comment: @VishalSharma I suggest you do some research on how to make UDP reliable. When a packet is received corrupt, send a nack or negative ack, and have the sender, send the packet again.

Comment: @VishalSharma In that case, I suggest you try to do the assignment and ask a specific question when you have a specific problem.

Comment: i have done when there is nak or checksum don't matches i dont want user to reenter the same text again in spite i stores the meesage and send it.

Comment: But the problem is a infinite loop is going again and again resending the wrong message.

Comment: Sounds like you have a bug in your code and you need to send the right message. Why do you think it is sending the wrong message?

Comment: Remember, what you are trying to implement has been implemented many, many times over the last few decades, learning from existing solutions will help you, which is where a little research can make a big difference.